# Can not insert cat-5 cable into iMac

Tags: mac, ethernet

[Note that I am a sysadmin, but this seemed more like a question for superuser than for serverfault].

I have a Apple iMac Intel (Early 2008) and can not insert a Cat-5 cable into the ethernet jack.  [I recall that, when we initially set up these sorts of computers, I had to force the cable in on some of them.]

Upon inspection, it appears that there are two springs inside the port that physically block access for inserting the cable.  I compared against another unit of the same type, and the springs were not blocking the cable there.  I can move one of the springs with a small screwdriver bit, but haven't been able to keep them out of the way.

And yes, the computer is off warranty.

Comment: I fiddled with the screwdriver some more and was able to get the springs out of the way and insert the cable.

Comment: Would you please either post that as an answer or delete the question?  This will show up in "unanswered questions" forever, left as-is.

Comment: Okay, I've put this as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it doesn't look like there are any other answers, so:

Fiddling with the screw driver some more, I was able to get the springs out of the way long enough to get a network cable in.